# Install Lamp & Perl on Redhat 5.5

Tags: redhat, lamp, perl

I need to install LAMP (including Perl) on a Redhat 5.5 machine.  (Note: I am fairly new to Linux, but did do a similar project with ubuntu.)  A good tutorial might suffice. Clients need to access a cgi-bin to run perl scripts (I don't yet know a lot about running perl scripts on the server side).

I found two tutorials that specifically mention RedHat (and are less then a year old according to Google). One seems simple and the other seems complicated:

1. https://help.databarracks.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1/1/installing-a-basic-lamp-stack-on-centos-or-redhat-enterprise-mysql-apache-php
2. http://www.lamphowto.com/

Other suggestions (as a replacement or supplemental) are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# yum -y install httpd mysql-server perl mod_perl
# service mysqld start
# service httpd start
```

Comment: Include the #s?

Comment: No, that's a root prompt, e.g., do it as the root user.